# How can I resolve a domain name to an IP address when the PHP functions fail?

Tags: php

I need to resolve any given domain in PHP to its corresponding IP address. [`gethostbyname`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830603/php-domain-to-ip) appears to perform a reverse DNS (rDNS) and isn't useful for obtaining the IP address of a domestic connection (that doesn't have direct rDNS).

I have the following, which of course doesn't work:

```
<?php
    if (ISSET($_POST["domain"])) {
        require_once("/protected/db.php");
        echo gethostbyname($_POST["domain"]);
    }
    echo "Error";
?>
```

Using `dns_get_record` returns `Array ( )` and doesn't appear to work as PHP prints `Array ( )` when I try the below code [from this answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1386156/2422013)

```
$result = dns_get_record($_POST["domain"],DNS_ALL);
print_r($result);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: @Machavity That doesn't provide an answer to my question (as per below).

Comment: How does it not answer it?

Comment: @Machavity See my edit. Perhaps I'm using it incorrectly and then I thought I might be confusing it by using a local address, but I'm using a proper public DNS name as the input (I'm `$_GET`'ing for testing) so I don't know.

Comment: Also, if it does turn out that I'm using it incorrectly then I'll gladly delete my answer and accept cegfaults'. I think like `gethostbyname`, `dns_get_record` has trouble with certain addresses such as the residential one that I'm using to test. I'm unsure what *certain addresses* actually is though, mine definitely has an rDNS so that can't be it, so it must be something else entirely.

Comment: Ok, that's different enough to not be a dupe. Reopened

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [dns_get_record()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php)

I would **strongly** advise against cybermonkey's solution, as shell_exec() (a) is platform-dependent, and (b) can have major security issues.

Comment: cybermonkey is the author of the question, though. ;)